# flutter: If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When i want to use sms auth with firebase the app fails only on iOS

The APN certificate is alredy configured on firebase and `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` is NO in `Info.plist`. The error is occuring during the verifyPhoneNumber method.

Here is the `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.7.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-PE)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Here is my code

```
void sendSms(String fullNumber) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: fullNumber,
      timeout: Duration(minutes: 1),
      verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
        _smsController?.add('loading');
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        _verifyUser(firebaseUser);
      },
      verificationFailed: (err) {
        print(err.message);
        print(err.code);
        _smsController?.add('UNKNOWN_ERROR');
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, [forceResendingToken]) {
        _verificationId = verificationId;
        _smsController?.add('code_sent');
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
    );
  }
```

And the error messages:

`flutter: If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.`

`flutter: verifyPhoneNumberError`

Answer (score 2):

Best Available Solution
AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [. 
UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
launchOptions)
}

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Pass device token to auth
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)

    // Pass device token to messaging
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    return super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
}

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handle-swizzle
override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                          didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                          fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Handle the message for firebase auth phone verification
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }

    // Handle it for firebase messaging analytics
    if ((notification["gcm.message_id"]) != nil) {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(notification)
    }

    return super.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
}

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                          options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    // Handle auth reCAPTCHA when silent push notifications aren't available
    if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
        return true
    }

    return super.application(application, open: url, options: options)
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what is being changed here?

Comment: Make sure to add these imports
```
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseMessaging
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

I found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35267#issuecomment-510420492) in flutter repository and currently works.

Replace the current `firebase_auth` version with

```
firebase_auth:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/collinjackson/plugins.git
      ref: 441417c2fed0ff26bf84a49ab2c5ffd2aa5487de
      path: packages/firebase_auth
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am using firebase messaging and phone auth in my flutter project, and I also facing the same issue for FCM notification with Image support.
In **ImageNotification** Project

```
// NotificationService.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

And,

```
// NotificationService.m
    
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
  if ([[FIRAuth auth] canHandleURL:url]) {
    return YES;
  }
  // URL not auth related; it should be handled separately.
    return NO;
}

- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene openURLContexts:(NSSet<UIOpenURLContext *> *)URLContexts {
  for (UIOpenURLContext *urlContext in URLContexts) {
    [FIRAuth.auth canHandleURL:urlContext.URL];
    // URL not auth related; it should be handled separately.
  }
}
```

This is working for me.
Thanks.